# Boost advocacy - help needed

Tags: c++, boost

> **Possible duplicates**
>   [Is there a reason to not use Boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226206/is-there-a-reason-to-not-use-boost)
>   [What are the advantages of using the C++ BOOST libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125580/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-the-c-boost-libraries)

OK, the high-level question is "Please provide me with what you consider to be the most effective arguments of why entire Boost, or some specific parts of it, should be compiled on our company's system and endorsed in software engineering standards".

Details of what I need:

- Would gladly accept both positive arguments (why install), as well as proposed rebuttals of likely counter-arguments I might hear (see question context below).
- Arguments should be made aimed at both technical Software Engineering team members and/or **very** technical senior managers - in other words, for the latter, the details of the argument may/should be technical, but the thrust of the argument should be "how would this make/save the company X money vs losing the company Y money as a cost of adding it to our toolset".

Context of the question:

- I'm a developer in a company with several hundred developers, many dosens of whom do C++.
- I had the (mis)fortune of being reassigned from my beloved Perl development spot to a team where I am also doing C++ development. So far I found numerous things that I could easily have done in Perl that are very hard/cumbersome to do in C++ (foreach loop as an example), and anytime I hit one of these, the answer 50% likely ends up being "You can't do this in standard C++ but you can do it with Boost"
- Our toolkit includes some legacy RogeWave libraries, and VERY limited number of Boost libraries (e.g. no regex, no foreach), of very old vintage.
- Any development must use libraries compiled and vetted by Software Engineering team. That is a hard and fast rule.
- SE team is somewhat resistant to adding new libraries, for a variety of reasons (e.g. effort to do this; functionality conflicts with RogeWave, for example for RegEx; the risk of installing and using any new software; cost of educating developers, etc...). They will add the libraries if presented with sufficient business need or majorly convincing cost/benefit ratio argument, but they have pretty tough threshold.

So, I'm looking for examples of which parts of Boost are so wonderful (with exact cost/benefit estimates) that installing them would be an Obviously Worth It Effort for Software Engineering.

Thanks in advance for any ideas/suggestions/examples.

Please don't mark this question as subjective as I am looking for measurable answers, not merely wonderful feelings :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wherever I worked in the last decade, when they had their own smart pointer class, I found bugs in that - usually within a few weeks. And, no, I never went and looked at it hoping to find errors.

I got into the habit of posting the following quote from the [TR1 smart pointer proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1450.html):

> The Boost developers found a shared-ownership smart pointer exceedingly difficult to implement correctly. Others have made the same observation. For example, Scott Meyers [Meyers01] says:
>
> > "The STL itself contains no reference-counting smart pointer, and writing a good one - one that works correctly all the time - is tricky enough that you don't want to do it unless you have to. I published the code for a reference-counting smart pointer in More Effective C++ in 1996, and despite basing it on established smart pointer implementations and submitting it to extensive pre- publication reviewing by experienced developers, a small parade of valid bug reports has trickled in for years. The number of subtle ways in which reference-counting smart pointers can fail is remarkable."

This plus a detailed analysis of the bug(s) I found usually got me the job of incorporating the boost libs into the code base. `:)`

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me you're doing this the wrong way around. Since proposals to add new libraries are going to be met with a lot of resistance, don't even bother trying to argue for boost *as a whole*. Choose your battles instead.

Find the specific Boost libraries which *you* know (with your knowledge of the application it's to be used in) will be useful and save time and money. And then propose adding those.

I could easily list the Boost libs I've found useful, and why I think they're great, but I don't know if they'll be of *any* use in your application.

Push for individual boost libraries to be included, and then perhaps, over time, so many of them will be included that it'll be simpler for everyone to just include all of Boost.

Comment: That'd be the likely path I'd need to take. Problem is that while the amount of advocacy needed for a specific boost library is less than the whole shebang, it still needs to be just as convincing and detailed on cost/benefit level. And i don't have nearly enough C++ experience to make those arguments myself (I'm 95% Perl guy these days skill-wise)

Comment: Fair enough, but the problem is that the rest of us don't really know which boost libraries would be relevant in your application. Most people find the smart pointers very valuable, and I tend to use type_traits a lot, but past that, it's really domain-specific which libraries are relevant.

Answer (score 7):

1. It's an open standard not controlled by a specific company ( no licensing costs )
2. It's cross platform
3. It's expertly designed / written and very fast / efficient extensively tested
4. There are open source implementations which your team can compile themselves.
5. Boost will soon become part of the standard C++ STL

Here is a slightly oldish 2005 article on Dr. Dobbs discussing the upcoming C++0x standard.

http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401958

Comment: +1 - except that not all of Boost is being incorporated into the next C++ standard, but Boost certainly is a significant influence on the new standard.

Comment: Isn't the last point a point *against* boost? why should they go through all the paperwork of adding a new library, if it'll be available as part of the standard in a few years?

Comment: @jalf, if they have to go through all that paperwork to add a library, imagine how much work they'll have to do to be allowed to upgrade their language to C++0X (whenever that comes out)

Comment: @glen - AMEN. The whole problem is not that they are against Boost but they need cost/benefit analysis for any work and change and disruptions.

Comment: @Robert - while these are all good and correct points, none of them provide the actual cost/benefit analysis that would be required for software engineering team. I need specific "this feature takes 3x amount of hours to maintain on homegrown code vs. Boost", "this feature is impossible to write without being Jon Skeet, but is in Boost and can save you 3 hrs dev work per 10000 lines of code" type of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I had to maintain a component using that old vintage Tools.h++ from Roguewave, on a Solaris system.

On Solaris, if we want to use boost, we need to use either gcc, or SunStudio with STLport implementation of the standard (instead of Roguewave one). And as Tools.h++ requires the old Roguewave pre-standard implementation of the standard -- on Solaris --, I had to give up on boost.

In the end I rewrote a simplified version of a few boost-like features I needed.

If you are in that same situation (*) , you would not be able to move from Roguewave library to boost that easily. There is a non negligible cost in this operation, as for instance pointer containers from both libraries have quite different interfaces.

(*) Where we can't slowly change bits by bits of the old code to progressively use boost. In that situation, the migration has to be radical and to change simultaneously every occurrence of Tools.h++ by something more trendy, or even better.

NB: Most people are able to progressively use boost in old projects, and may miss a very important, and yes technical, point. Hence my *negative* answer.

Answer (score 2):

Boost is a great tool and an invaluable part of our product development (we'd be lost without smart_ptr)... but because it is changing so fast the stability of releases can be effected.

For example, we were happily introducing new versions of Boost as soon as they came out without thinking twice. That is until we were stung with a bug in the 1.35 threading library that produced occassional (ie difficult to debug) but critical errors. Fortunately we identified the issue before anything was released to the public and could move back to 1.34.

Ever since then we've taken a specific version, extensively tested it, and not updated without a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Yep. That's what I'm up against - the (quite correct for our company) Don't Fix It If It Ain't Broke development philosophy. Which is great for developing stable code, but requires double efforts to introduce something new and exciting when that new thing is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions for advocating boost:

**Who's Using Boost?** (http://www.boost.org/users/uses.html)

lots of major projects use boost: (e.g., adobe photoshop, CERN)

**Boost Project Cost** (http://www.boost.org/development/index.html)

How much it would cost to hire a team to write boost from scratch? There's a nifty (somewhat gimmicky) calculator there that helps to put it in perspective.